# Prove continuity of complex function $z^2/|z|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Let $f(z)$ be the complex function $z^2/|z|$. Prove that it is continuous at all complex numbers $z_0$, by the usual $ε-δ$ definition.

I proved the case $z_0 = 0$, but I'm stuck when $z_0$ is any other complex number. More specifically, I understand that I need to add and subtract something to the numerator of the expression$ ||z_0|z^2 - |z|(z_0)^2|/|z||z_0|$, but I cannot find what. Thanks!

Comment: $f(0)$ is undefined, so how did you prove it for $z=0$?

Comment: @DavidPeterson oh sorry, we further define $f(0) = 0$

Comment: Hint: $0\le \frac{|(z+h)^2|z|-z^2|z+h||}{|z||z+h|}\le \frac{|(z+h)^2|z|-z^2|z||+|z^2||h|}{|z||z+h|}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the behaviour of $z^2/|z|$ is abberant at $z = 0$, I would definitely recommend restricting your $\delta$ from the outset so that $z = 0$ is not a consideration. If we take a point $z_0 \in \Bbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, we should guarantee that $\delta$ is small enough so that
$$|z - z_0| < \delta \implies z \neq 0.$$
How do we do this? We could ensure that $\delta \le |z_0| / 2$, i.e. our $\delta$ can never be more than half the distance between $z_0$ and $0$. Then,
$$|z - z_0| < \delta \implies |z_0| - |z| \le |z - z_0| < |z_0|/ 2 \implies |z| > |z_0| / 2 > 0.$$

With this assumption in mind, let's begin (as we often do in $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs) at the end. We have,
$$\left|\frac{z^2}{|z|} - \frac{z_0^2}{|z_0|} \right| < \varepsilon \impliedby \frac{\Big|z^2|z_0| - z_0^2|z|\Big|}{|z||z_0|} < \varepsilon.$$
under our assumption, $|z| > |z_0| / 2$, hence
$$\frac{\Big|z^2|z_0| - z_0^2|z|\Big|}{|z||z_0|} < \frac{2}{|z_0|^2} \cdot\Big|z^2|z_0| - z_0^2|z|\Big|.$$
This removes the wildcard of having $z$ appear in the denominator. If we can make the right hand side less than $\varepsilon$ (spoiler alert: we can), then the left hand side will also be less than $\varepsilon$.

Next, observe that $z_0^2|z|$ is approximately $z_0^2|z_0|$. We can use the usual trick using triangle inequality:
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{|z_0|^2} \cdot\Big|z^2|z_0| - z_0^2|z|\Big| &\le \frac{2}{|z_0|^2} \cdot\left(\Big|z^2|z_0| - z_0^2|z_0|\Big| + \Big|z_0^2|z_0| - z_0^2|z|\Big|\right) \\
&= \frac{2}{|z_0|^2} \cdot\left(|z^2 - z_0^2| \cdot |z_0| + |z_0|^2 \cdot \Big||z_0| - |z|\Big|\right).
\end{align*}
Note that $\Big||z_0| - |z|\Big| \le |z - z_0|$, so we can control the latter term. The former term is
$$|z^2 - z_0^2| \cdot |z_0| = |z - z_0| \cdot |z + z_0| \cdot |z_0|.$$
We can control $|z - z_0|$, so provided we can guarantee that $|z + z_0|$ doesn't get too big, we can control the whole expression.

Fortunately, we have our assumption that $|z - z_0| < |z_0| / 2$, because
$$|z + z_0| \le |z - z_0| + 2|z_0| < 5|z_0| / 2,$$
hence under our assumption,
\begin{align*}\frac{2}{|z_0|^2} \cdot\left(|z^2 - z_0^2| \cdot |z_0| + |z_0|^2 \cdot \Big||z_0| - |z|\Big|\right) &< \frac{2}{|z_0|^2} \cdot\left(|z - z_0| \cdot \frac{5|z_0|}{2} \cdot |z_0| + |z_0|^2 \cdot |z - z_0|\right) \\
&= 7|z - z_0|.
\end{align*}
Thus, if we can ensure that $7|z - z_0| < \varepsilon$ and that $|z - z_0| < |z_0| / 2$, then
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon &> 7|z - z_0| \\
&> \frac{2}{|z_0|^2} \cdot\left(|z^2 - z_0^2| \cdot |z_0| + |z_0|^2 \cdot \Big||z_0| - |z|\Big|\right) \\
&\ge \frac{2}{|z_0|^2} \cdot\Big|z^2|z_0| - z_0^2|z|\Big| \\
&> \left|\frac{z^2}{|z|} - \frac{z_0^2}{|z_0|} \right|.
\end{align*}
In other words, choose
$$\delta = \min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{7}, \frac{|z_0|}{2}\right\}.$$